# how to post json file using curl

Tags: curl

Im using fast api python
this is my request get who takes as inputs file json , Number_option , canal and Numper_phone

```
curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000/get_option Number_phone=12345678&canal=ussd&Option_Number=4&json_data=d.json' -H 'accept: application/json'
```

I want to post the same json file and and the other inputs in the same request Im using this request but no response :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @home/test.json
```

any solution?